# I'm getting name error while coding to make YouTube downloader

Tags: python

This the code which I'm using to create a GUI for YouTube video downloader

```
#import) tkinter as tk

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("My GUI")

# Create label
label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello, World!")

# Lay out label
label.pack()

# Run forever!
root.mainloop()
```

I'm getting error something like this below in my Terminal

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "YoutubeVideoDownloader.py", line 4, in <module>
    root = tk.Tk()
NameError: name 'tk' is not defined
Process finished with exit code 1.
```

please look at the Image I've shared here

Comment: Did you mean not to comment out the import of `tkinter`?

Comment: What does `#import) tkinter as tk` mean?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the package first, you can do that by using `pip`. Run this on your project directory folder using some sort of cmd / terminal.

```
pip install tk
```

Just un-comment the import

```py
import tkinter as tk
```

The line above tells python to import the library tkinter as tk. You can then use `tk.TK()` to initialize tkinter library.

Comment: Please clear a bit more, this code is not running saying name tk is not defined

Comment: Under which circumstances do you ever need : ‘pip install tk’?

Comment: @quamrana when you don't have tkinter library installed on your machine.

Comment: Tkinter is part of the standard library and [`tk` on PyPI has nothing to do with Tkinter](https://pypi.org/search/?q=tk).